# how to link object file of different directory using cmd?

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors

I am using windows and mingw.
this is my program looks like

```
helloworld
|---include
|   |---header1
|       |---headerA.cpp
|       |---headerA.h
|       |---headerA.o
|---main.cpp
|---main.o
```

I included header`#include"header1/headerA.h"` successfully by commamd: `g++ -c main.cpp -I.\include`
but when I tried to link `main.o` and `headerA.o` using command: `g++ -o main main.o -I.\include\header1\*.o` i have tried many commands but got error : **main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to ``foo()'
collect2.exe:
error: ld returned 1 exit status**. please tell how can I link them properly. I don't want to include header like `#include"C:/../headerA.h"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html), `-I` flag is used to pass include directories where compiler will look for headers. Your error is a linker error instead. This means that you compiled your translation unit correctly, but when linker tried to resolve symbols, it could not find the definitions. Headers contain only the declarations, not the "meat".

You simply list all .o files which you'd like to link together:
`g++ main.o ./include/header1/headerA.o -o main`

**As a side note** you shouldn't put .o files in /include directory of your project. Preferably, you should create a dedicated /build directory for object files (to not mess the main project - you wouldn't like to push them to a repository, right?).

Comment: thank you, sir. I have a another question if I want to build my project for both windows and Linux using different makefiles. is it possible? or can you tell me how professional 
 independent platform projects are built?

Comment: If you are using mingw and stick to platform independent conatructs in your code, you'll have no problems with building it for both linux and windows using g++ directly as you do (and same makefile I believe). But soon you'll have a dependency mess, thus I recommend using **scons** or **CMake**. They abstract away compiler instructions, however they've got their own syntax which you have to grasp.